# How to export Yii2 migrations into docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, yii2-basic-app

I have successfully containerized my basic Yii2 application with docker and it runs on `localhost:8000`. However, I cannot use the app effectively as most of its data are stored in migration files. Is there a way I could export the migrations into docker after running it? (or during execution)

This is my docker compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: yiisoftware/yii2-php:7.1-apache
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ./:/app:delegated
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    networks:
      - my-network
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my-db
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - mydb:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
     - my-network
  memcached:
    container_name: memcached
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
        - "0.0.0.0:11211:11211"
volumes:
  restatdb:
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.4

ADD . /

COPY ./config/web.php ./config/web.php

COPY . /var/www/html

# Let docker create a volume for the session dir.
# This keeps the session files even if the container is rebuilt.
VOLUME /var/www/html/var/sessions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run yii commands in docker. First let the yii2 container run in the background or another tab of the terminal. The yii commands can be run using the `docker exec` on the interactive interface which would let us interact with the running container

`sudo docker exec -i <container-ID> php yii migrate/up`

You can get the container ID using

`sudo docker ps`